# is there anything wrong with this If Condition in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web, chart.js

I have "if condition" in javascript code like this

```
for (var i in data) {
  //Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
  if (data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1) {
    Gender.push("Men");
  }
  if (data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2) {
    Gender.push("Women");
  } else {
    Gender.push("Other");
  }

  jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "A") {
    Fakultas.push("FAPERTA");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "B") {
    Fakultas.push("FKH");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "C") {
    Fakultas.push("FPIK");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "D") {
    Fakultas.push("FAPET");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "E") {
    Fakultas.push("FAHUTAN");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "F") {
    Fakultas.push("FATETA");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "G") {
    Fakultas.push("FMIPA");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "H") {
    Fakultas.push("FEM");
  }

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "I") {
    Fakultas.push("FEMA");
  } else {
    Fakultas.push("Other");
  }

  jumlah_orang.push(data[i].jumlah_orang);
}
```

I took the data from the database with query. Here is the table of db
[image] [image]

but the result came like this
[image]

how can I make the chart to be correct? Because I just want 1 "other" in every chart. Please help me to solve that problem thankyou. GBU

Comment: You need else if for every condition, otherwise your else is entered for every case but when the if directly above is true. That probably doesn't explain the chart though. You would have to show what chart data and configs you are providing.

Comment: More specifically, your count for "Other" is sum(Other)+sum(1), ie you count Men in Other as well - just add a "else" between `if(1)` and `if(2)`. `if (data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1) { ... } else if ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "other" condition inside the for loop triggers each time you iterate through the data, and all if conditions inside the loop fails.
So if you can push the "other" to the objects after for loop, each chart will contain one "other".

Can you please correct me if my understanding is wrong?

```
for(var i in data)
        {
            //Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
            if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1)
            {
                Gender.push("Men");
            } 
            if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2)
            {
                Gender.push("Women");
            }

            jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "A")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAPERTA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "B")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FKH");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "C")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FPIK");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "D")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAPET");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "E")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FAHUTAN");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "F")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FATETA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "G")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FMIPA");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "H")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FEM");
            }

            if(data[i].Fakultas == "I")
            {
                Fakultas.push("FEMA");
            }

            jumlah_orang.push(data[i].jumlah_orang);
        }
        Gender.push("Other");
        Fakultas.push("Other");
```

Comment: That wouldn't count how many others there is. His chart problem is somewhere else.

Comment: yeah, it works. the "other" appear just one time in every chart. but the data that is "jumlah_orang" isn't incorrect. do you know how to solve that problem? but the data that is "jumlah" is already correct @nagendrakumarkasam

Answer (score 1):

From your descripion, I think it can be solved using `else if` as shown below.

```
for (var i in data) {
  //Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
  if (data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1) {
    Gender.push("Men");
  }else if (data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2) {
    Gender.push("Women");
  } else {
    Gender.push("Other");
  }

  jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);

  if (data[i].Fakultas == "A") {
    Fakultas.push("FAPERTA");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "B") {
    Fakultas.push("FKH");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "C") {
    Fakultas.push("FPIK");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "D") {
    Fakultas.push("FAPET");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "E") {
    Fakultas.push("FAHUTAN");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "F") {
    Fakultas.push("FATETA");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "G") {
    Fakultas.push("FMIPA");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "H") {
    Fakultas.push("FEM");
  }else if (data[i].Fakultas == "I") {
    Fakultas.push("FEMA");
  } else {
    Fakultas.push("Other");
  }

  jumlah_orang.push(data[i].jumlah_orang);
}
```

Or if `A` to `I` are constants  you can do like this also

```
var mapping = {
  "A" : "FAPERTA",
  "B" : "FKH",
  "C" : "FPIK",
  "D" : "FAPET",
  "E" : "FAHUTAN",
  "F" : "FATETA",
  "G" : "FMIPA",
  "H" : "FEM",
  "I" : "FEMA"
};

for (var i in data) {
  //Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
  if (data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1) {
    Gender.push("Men");
  }else if (data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2) {
    Gender.push("Women");
  } else {
    Gender.push("Other");
  }

  jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);

  var value = mapping[data[i].Fakultas];
  if(value){
    Fakultas.push(value);
  }else{
    Fakultas.push("Other");
  }

  jumlah_orang.push(data[i].jumlah_orang);
}
```